# Upgrade Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

A friend of mine has a PC with Windows 7 Ultimate and he wants to upgrade to Windows 10 Home without reinstalling applications, the same way as Windows update. Is it possible, even if he has to change the serial number before the installation?

Answer (score 0):

I had W7 Ultimate. The upgrade offered is to W10 Pro as stated in MS equivalence table.

Most applications will remain installed as they were before update. I only lost Adobe Acrobat Pro (which had an old invalid license) and Speccy (dunno why it got lost). The update process assigns you a new W10 license and activates it without your intervention.

UPDATE: The update can be done from a downloaded ISO (from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)) but it does not let you choose between home and pro editions on the download. Anyway, keep the old W7 license key at hand (write it down or something) just in case.

Comment: I mean without the use of Windows update he doesn't have unlimited Internet and he might not want the pro edition

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this question & your later comment are most confusing.

Is this just an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) ?
Does he specifically **want** Win 10 Home, or do you think that is your solution because **you** have WIn 10 Home already & think you can save his data download requirement?

Either way - carefully work through http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install - get the media creation tool on *your* machine (presumably one without a limited data connection), create the USB stick by selecting "Create installation media for another PC." then run that created USB key on his machine from the USB stick.
***Do not boot from it***, double-click the setup.exe from his running system.

The end result will be an upgraded, activated Windows 10 **Pro**, as that is what his license allows.

Comment: my friend doesnt have internet connection ... so he asks if he buys windows home

Comment: but you do... follow the steps to make a USB key - then he can have win10 Pro for free...

Comment: & you really ought to clarify your question. It contains no mention of limited or no internet connection, which is making people have to backtrack their answers. The 'Home' update idea contains no reasoning & is, in fact, irrelevant after comments. Did you read what an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) is & realise why this **is** one?

Answer (score -1):

To upgrade to W10 you have to install ALL Windows Updates and after few restarts it should auto suggest you to install W10 upgrade.

Comment: The OP wants to do with without additional downloads.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: My mistake, english not mother language:)